# Retry opening website in Python when there is a timeout

Tags: python, timeout, urllib2

I am opening a lot of connections to a website. I don't know why, but ever now and then the connection times out?

```
subpage=html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(subpage_url,timeout=5).read())
```

I use the urllib2 library now, because you can set the timeout, previously I used urllib, where there was no timeout time to be set so when the connection failed you had to wait very long.

As I said before I have no idea why the connection fails sometimes, maybe it has something to do with the fact that I am trying to do this from the university wireless connection. That is why I would like to retry to establish the connection when there is a timeout.

Comment: Keep in mind that instead of your wireless connection, the site may thing your "a lot of connections" is a denial-of-service attack and they might end up blocking your IP entirely if you proceed. Have you read their robots.txt?

Comment: I didn't know what robots.txt is. I checked it out now, but I am not sure what to make of it. The website in question is http://www.oddsportal.com/.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import time
data = ''
started = time()
while data == '' and time() - started < 30:
    data=html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(subpage_url,timeout=5).read())
if len(data) <= 0:
    print('Failed to retrieve your page 6 times, check your internet connection!')
```

You'll probably get an exception here, handle that with a `try` block and you should be golden.